# Which version of log4j is used in Liferay 7.2

Tags: log4j, liferay, liferay-7.2

I use liferay 7.2.1 GA2, and its have log4j inside. But I can't figure out where it is and which version of it used in liferay. The only thing i found is liferay package `com.liferay.portal.log4j.extender` in app manager.

Which version of log4j used in liferay? Is it possible to update it for liferay?

Comment: As it appears to be a paid service, it seems like this should be a question for `Liferay`? ... after all, they should be able to answer, especially due to the latest security issue related to `log4j`.

Comment: In my case I use free version of portal. I thought maybe somebody understands this thing better than me and can answer.

Comment: You can probably search the `bundle` with `find /server/liferay -name "*log4j*.jar" -ls` and see JARS on your distribution.

Comment: Bare in mind, Tomcat is exploded and any WAR files are exploded dynamically (at runtime). I believe there is ElasticSearch at least in Liferay 7.3. I agreed with @Paul T about the Liferay commercial, they seem brilliantly slow at remediating this fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Liferay Portal 7.2 uses **log4j 1.2.17**

You can check the libraries used by Liferay Portal 7.2 in the **lib/versions.html** file in the source code, see log4j version of Liferay Portal 7.2 here:

- https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/ded0e9390637985231e962e4ad4cfa4639eabb26/lib/versions.html#L2937-L2942

If you are asking this question due to the [Log4j 2.x Zero-Day Vulnerability](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html#Fixed_in_Log4j_2.15.0), it only affects to the Liferay Portal 7.4 version.

For more information see this post: https://liferay.dev/blogs/-/blogs/log4j2-zero-day-vulnerability

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Elasticsearch sidecar (bundled Elasticsearch), liferay starts an additional process on startup. As far as I know, this one is using log4j-core 2.13.3.

There are blogpost that state the elasticsearch is not directly affected and usually those port should not be exposed - so you should make this sure.